# How can I perform stepwise feature selection with WLS in Python?

Tags: python, linear-regression, feature-selection, weighted

I want to conduct stepwise feature selection for a weighted least squares regression model in Python.

I have set up X_train, y_train, and weights as the independent variables (dataframe), dependent variable (series), and weights (series).

I will use the statsmodels api to train the final model:

```
import stats models.formula.api as sm

model = sm.wls(formula = 'target ~'+'+'.join(selected_vars),
weights = weights,
data = pd.concat([X_train[selected_vars], y_train], axis=1))

results=model.fit()
```

What package can I use for the stepwise feature selection with WLS?

I have tried using

```
sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelection
```

However, the fit method does not permit the use of weights as well as the variables.